# How can I disable keyboard input in DateTimeField widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make a [DateTimeField](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield#-readme-tab-) widget in my Flutter application. But after I picked a date in that field, I still can edit the field with the Keyboard that appear after I clicked the field.  I did like the following. How can I disable this keyboard for this widget?

```
DateTimeField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  format: format,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Tanggal Lahir",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    ),
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
    return showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(1990,1,1),
      initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime(2000,6,16),
        lastDate: DateTime(2010,12,30));
     },
   ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// set readOnly property to true,

DateTimeField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  format: format,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Tanggal Lahir",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    ),
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
    return showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(1990,1,1),
      initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime(2000,6,16),
        lastDate: DateTime(2010,12,30));
     },

      readOnly: true,  //Add this line


     ),
```

Comment: Thanks, it's help me a lot

Answer (score 3):

**just add read only parameter**

```
         DateTimeField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            format: format,
            readOnly: true,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Tanggal Lahir",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
            onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
              return showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  firstDate: DateTime(1990, 1, 1),
                  initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime(2000, 6, 16),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2010, 12, 30));
            },
          ),
```